# How to enable property injection on controllers using Autofac and ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-mvc

There doesn't really seem to be an easy way to make sure the controllers have property injection.

A way around it would be to register all controllers individually, which seems to defeat the purpose a bit. The `[FromServices]` attribute is [removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3578) and they specifically mention it should be up to the individual IoC containers to make sure this happens.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious? Looked for all available extension methods but didn't find anything, same for issues and the discussion forum.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything here. These problems have been [reported to the MVC team](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3727#issuecomment-210836460), but until now Microsoft seems to ignore this.

Comment: @Steven that was a slightly shocking read. Do you reckon it's worth raising another issue about? I'm not 100% sure on the technical details (ReleaseController + having a separate container) but the use case (in my case) is quite simple, wanting property injection on my controllers.

Comment: I'm fine with raising a new issue with Microsoft, but why do you need property injection?

Comment: Simply a preference really, my controllers are generally quite composite and relay most of their stuff to providers. The providers are separated using IProvide and IManage interfaces to ensure certain parts of the system can only read and others can manage. Combined that makes for a decent amount of injections and it's just a bit of clutter to read that an AccountController takes an IProvideAccounts, IManageAccounts, RoleManager, UserManager, SignInManager, ILoggerFactory  as parameters. I can split the controller up but that has it's own downsides.

Comment: I really think you should rather split up controllers or move to a model where you can dispatch query or commands by using a single abstraction. You can read about such model [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: Thanks, that is certainly a possibility. Most of the results/actions of those IProvide and IManage are already very much like that and hardly need any controller work, convenience makes me prefer to keep account related things in one controller. That's a whole different discussion though. Even if it would only be three parameters, or even one, I generally prefer for these type of classes that frameworks instantiate to be property injected, I'll never wire one up manually. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Do note though that hopefully with C# 7 we will lose much of the cruft we see to day with constructor injection. The expectation is that defining constructor dependencies will take the same amount of code in C# 7 as properties would do in C# 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, setting up property injection for controllers with autofac is a bit tricky ;) but here is how it works.

With ASP.NET Core (2.1) you first need to register your controllers as services in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

otherwise property injection won't work as quoted from the [autofac docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services):

> By default, ASP.NET Core will resolve the controller parameters from the container but doesn’t actually resolve the controller from the container. This usually isn’t an issue but it does mean: [...] **Special wiring that you may have done during registration of the controller (like setting up property injection) won’t work**.

You then need to register your services with the autofac container builder via `populate` and afterwards you can register your controllers with the autofac container.

Here is a shortened code excerpt from the [autofac docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services):

```
  public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);
    builder.RegisterType<MyController>().PropertiesAutowired();
    this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
  }
```

It is important that you append `.PropertiesAutowired()` to allow property injection!

Now **another thing to mention which may not be obvious** is that autofac's `PropertiesAutowired` does not automatically consider every property of your service to be worty for property injection.

Checkout the `DefaultPropertySelector` from the [github source code](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/797c5cff0c3688e3a64c695805d1ab699f756db5/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/DefaultPropertySelector.cs#L48) and you will see it will skip non-public ones:

```
if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite || propertyInfo.SetMethod?.IsPublic != true)
{
    return false;
}
```

So you may need to create a custom `PropertySelector` that extends the `DefaultPropertySelector` in order to register the properties as being injectable based on your own logic. So you could do something like this:

```
var propSelector = new MyPropertySelector();
builder.RegisterType<MyController>().PropertiesAutowired(propSelector);
```

In order to make sure that you do not always have to remember each single controller class, you can also register all your controllers in bulk:

```
builder.Populate(services);
var propSelector = new MyPropertySelector();
builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Controller).Assembly)
  .AssignableTo<Controller>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  .PropertiesAutowired(propSelector);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
builder.Populate(services);
var propSelector = new MyPropertySelector();
builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Controller).Assembly)
  .AssignableTo<Controller>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  .PropertiesAutowired(propSelector);
```

but it didn't work for me so instead I used the below code snippet that I took from the official site.

```
var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
               .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
               .PropertiesAutowired();
```

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html