# Assigning all controllers with one register In DI Container

Tags: .net-core, autofac

I have a fairly simple question, I am testing Autofac DI container under .net core 2.0 now for example i have a controller

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestModel _testModel;

    public ValuesController(ITestModel testModel)
    {
        _testModel = testModel;
    }
}
```

And registered DI in startup:

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<TestModel>().As<ITestModel>();
        builder.Populate(services);
        var container = builder.Build();

        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

It works fine, but I've been wondering, what about if ill have twenty of those controllers and some 20 more logic classes with constructor with parameters with some interface do i need to register them in same manner, It would get really ugly in no time. So my question is, is it possible to register all controllers and classes that has only interfaces as parameters at once in this environment??

Comment: Take a look at the concept of [assembly scanning](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html) in the Autofac documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the in comment was said, assembly scanning but with all referenced(filtered by interface of course), assembles did work as planned.

Answer (score 0):

```
            builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(HomeController).Assembly)
            .AssignableTo<Controller>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Be sure to reference a Controller in your project (`HomeController` in this case)

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982317/224410)